# Entity framework, Foreign Key referencing last Id was inserted, and also a collection of previous ones on the same table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am facing this issue:
I want the `MallWorker` to have a reference to the last `Sell` registrated, but also to the historical ones that happened before. It is a "2 x Foreign key" to the same table, but I don't have any idea about how to configure it so it does not complains about multiplicites.

```cs
public class MallWorker
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string WorkerName{get;set;}
    public int IdLastSell{get;set;}
    public Sell IdLastSellNavigation{get;set;}
    public ICollection<Sell> SellsHistoricalData{get;set;}
}

public class Sell
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int IdMallWorker{get;set;}
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
    public MallWorker IdMallWorkerNavigation{get;set;}
}
```

How can I configure Entity framework 6, to handle this situation?

Comment: Is it for EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: EF6, it is written in the last sentencene :)

Comment: Yes, I saw. But you added EF Core tag.

Comment: Oh yes, it is fixed now

Comment: The property `IdLastSellNavigation` is type of `Sell`, but the OP's code show a class `LastShell`. Mistake?

Comment: fixed @Vernou , i got a long day

Comment: Also, fix `IdMallWorkerNavigation` from `int` to `MallWorker` in `Sell`  ;)

Comment: Is there a possibility that a sell might be associated to more than one worker?

Answer (score 0):

That's fine, except you need to make IdSell nullable, or you will never be able to insert any rows because you have a required circular dependency, and SQL Server checks all Foreign Keys on INSERT.

EG:

```
public class MallWorker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WorkerName { get; set; }
    public int? IdLastSell { get; set; }
    public Sell IdLastSellNavigation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Sell> SellsHistoricalData { get; set; }
}

public class Sell
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int IdMallWorker { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public MallWorker IdMallWorkerNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

So you can insert a MallWorker, follwed by multiple Sells, and then update the MallWorder's IdSell.  Note your model doesn't guarantee that the MallWorker's LastSellNavigation is one of their own Sell entities.

So a better model is probably:

```
public class MallWorker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WorkerName { get; set; }
    public int? IdLastSale { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id,IdLastSale")]
    public MallWorkerSale LastSale { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MallWorkerSale> Sales { get; } = new HashSet<MallWorkerSale>();
}

public class MallWorkerSale
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int IdMallWorker { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public MallWorker MallWorker{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What  about the code first configuration? I am interested in how to configure it on EF6

Comment: That will work fine by convention.  No additional configuration is necessary.

Comment: I get this error => Circular relationships with referential integrity constraints detected.Can you provide Code first code?